# How to configure Github desktop (Windows) [credential]to work with AWS CodeCommit and MFA

Tags: git, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I configured global gitconfig and removed `[credential]` section. I added `[credential]` section to my user config `C:\Users\me\.gitconfig`. I specify which AWS profile to use, create MFA temporary access token. Everything works fine from command line and VS Code.
I checked Github desktop internal Git config and found at `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.6\resources\app\git\etc\gitconfig`. I removed `[credential]`  section. When I pull from command line using Github desktop built in git (I specify full path to git.exe), everything works fine. When I try to pull from Github desktop gui, it asks my credentials. I know that git merges setting from global/user/repo settings. All settings are merged **excep credential managers**. Credential managers are chained. When first credential manager returns true, chain processing is stopped. Problem with Github desktop is that it uses own configuration and that credential manager is chained as first.
I had similar problem with VS 2019 professional. When fixing its own internal gitconfig, VS 2019 works fine.
I checked iGithub desktop integration documentation at https://github.com/desktop/desktop/tree/development/docs/integrations but no mentioning of AWS CodeCommit.
How to force Github desktop to use global/user gitconfig?

Note:
I used faked email address in my Github desktop git settings and searched file system where is that e-mail stored. It is not anywhere under Github desktop folder nor registry.